# How to manually release stack memory after the thread is forcefully killed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminate

I am using a watchdog thread to monitor a child thread in visual c++, and the watchdog will terminate the child and create a new child thread, if it stop sending events to watchdog after certain length of time. In my testing, I repeatedly terminate and re-spawn the child thread, before it has chance to exit, and I've found that it causes memory leak. My main suspicious is due to the stack memory created by the child and failed to release when it was terminated. Is there any way for the watchdog thread to manually release the stack memory for the child thread, before re-spawn a new child thread? I actually using this method to kill off any freeze thread and so far TerminateThread() is the only choice I can have. Below is a simple illustration on how I did the test. Thank you.

```
void watchdogFunc (void)
{
    while(true){
        child  = CreateThread(NULL, 0, childFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
        TerminateThread(child, 1);
    }
}

void childFunc (void)
{
    while(true){} //simulated thread freeze
}
```

Comment: how do you know there's a memory leak?

Comment: Well, this is for pthreads, but the point seems to carry over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163090/when-i-kill-a-pthread-in-c-do-destructors-of-objects-on-stacks-get-called

Comment: The memory leak is probable because of the memory you allocated in the thread. Not the stack.

Comment: @Anonymous-SOS, using even a standard container like `std::vector` and killing the thread will leak, so it's nothing the OP allocates directly.

Comment: Also, why not use `std::thread`s?

Comment: My point was that it is not the stack. Directly or not, it is something in the heap that is leaking.  TerminateThread will free the stack https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Anonymous-SOS, but it will not call destructors, which is what programming with value semantics in C++ is all about.

Comment: StoryTeller: still not the stack. Again, heap.

Comment: Bottom line is using TerminateThread is almost always wrong, and if you're leaking memory then you're allocating (directly or indirectly) - which proves it's wrong in your case.  Memory allocation by a thread that might be asynchronously cancelled could occasionally leave the heap corrupt or with locks held, such that other threads may lock up later.  Maybe only one time in 10, or 1 in 10,000,000, and it might be more for someone else running your app than it is for you.  Your watchdog/monitoring thread should just set a flag asking the thread to close itself the next time it checks.

Comment: I did use the SetEvent() to signal the abort, but I will only TerminateThread() after certain amount of time if the child thread doesn't signal back and exitThread. By the way, my code was initially using std::thread child method to create a thread, but the thread keeps running after i called child.~thread().

Comment: How do I know the memory leaking?? I was monitoring the Resource Monitor in real time, and the memories' growing. By the way, all these things are actually running as a windows service.

Comment: @Charles You should not be calling the destructor explicitly. The way forward is to fix the issue of the threads not finishing gracefully instead of adding layers of hacks to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`TerminateThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The system frees the thread's initial stack.

You're barking up the wrong tree.

You should certainly use the C++ thread class, not `CreateThread()/TerminateThread()` directly.