# Is gettimeofday async signal safe ? and can it cause deadlock if used in signal handler?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, signals

Previously I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391701/pthread-kill-vs-pthread-cancel-to-terminate-a-thread-blocked-for-i-o) regarding how to terminate thread blocked for I/O. I have used `pthread_kill()` instead of `pthread_cancel()` or writing to pipes, considering few advantages. After implementing the code to send signal (SIGUSR2) to the target thread using `pthread_kill()`, initially it worked fine and didn't face any issues.

```
static void signalHandler(int signum) {
    LogInfo("SIGNAL HANDLER : %d",signum);  //print info message using logger utility
}

void setSignalHandler() {
    struct sigaction actions;

    memset(&actions, 0, sizeof(actions));
    sigemptyset(&actions.sa_mask);
    actions.sa_flags = 0;
    actions.sa_handler = signalHandler;

    int rc = sigaction(SIGUSR2,&actions,NULL);
    if(rc < 0) {
        LogError("Error in sigaction");  //print error using logger utility
    }
}

void stopThread() {
    fStop = 1;  //set the flag to stop the thread
    if( ftid ) { //ftid is pthread_t variable of thread that needs to be terminated.
        LogInfo("Before pthread_kill()");
        int kill_result = pthread_kill(ftid,SIGUSR2);  // send signal to interrupt the thread if blocked for poll() I/O
        LogInfo("pthread_kill() returned : %d ( %s )",kill_result,strerror(kill_result));
        int result = pthread_join( ftid, NULL );
        LogInfo("Event loop stopped for %s", fStreamName);
        LogInfo( "pthread_join() -> %d ( %s )\n", result, strerror(result) );
        if( result == 0 ) ftid = 0;
    }
}
```

Recently I have noticed a deadlock issue where few threads (which tried to log statements) blocked with below stacktrace

```
#0  0x00007fc1b2dc565c in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc1b2d70f0c in _L_lock_2462 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc1b2d70d47 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000000004708f7 in Logger::getCurrentTimestamp(char*) ()
```

`getCurrentTimestamp(char*)` function is called from our logger module when `LogInfo()` or `LogError()` functions are invoked. This function internally calls gettimeofday() to print the current time in logs. So I'm suspecting `LogInfo()` function (which calls `gettimeofday()`) called inside signalHandler() might be causing the deadlock issue. But i'm not confident of this as this issue is not getting reproduced frequently and i did not get any information stating that `gettimeofday()` is not async signal safe.

gettimeofday() is [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220224/is-the-gettimeofday-function-thread-safe-in-linux) and i'm considering it's not async signal safe as it was not listed under [async signal safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

1) Can I consider `gettimeofday()` is not async signal safe and it was the root cause of deadlock ?

2) Are there any known issues where use of `pthread_kill()` might cause deadlock ?

**EDIT :**

Below is the definition of `getCurrentTimeStamp()` function

```
char* Logger::getCurrentTimestamp ( char *tm_buff ) {
    char curr_time[ 32 ] = { 0 };
    time_t current = time( NULL );
    struct timeval detail_time;

    if ( tm_buff ) {
        strftime( curr_time, sizeof(curr_time), "%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime( &current ) );
        gettimeofday( &detail_time, NULL );
        sprintf( tm_buff, "%s:%03d", curr_time, (int) (detail_time.tv_usec / 1000) );
        return (tm_buff);
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

stack trace of the thread that was interrupted by signal.

```
#0  0x00007fc1b2dc565c in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc1b2d70f0c in _L_lock_2462 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc1b2d70d47 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000000004708f7 in Logger::getCurrentTimestamp(char*) ()
#4  0x000000000046e80f in Log::write(Logger*, LogType, std::string const&, char const*) ()
#5  0x000000000046df74 in Log::i(Logger*, char const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, char const*, ...) ()
#6  0x0000000000456b67 in ?? ()
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x00007fc1b2da8dc5 in _xstat () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#9  0x00007fc1b2d71056 in __tzfile_read () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#10 0x00007fc1b2d703b4 in tzset_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#11 0x00007fc1b2d70d63 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#12 0x00000000004708f7 in Logger::getCurrentTimestamp(char*) ()
#13 0x000000000047030e in Logger::writeLog(int, std::string&, std::string&) ()
#14 0x0000000000470633 in Logger::Write(Logger*, int, std::string, std::string const&) ()
#15 0x000000000046eb02 in Log::write(Logger*, LogType, std::string const&, char const*) ()
#16 0x000000000046df74 in Log::i(Logger*, char const*, std::string const&, std::string const&, char const*, ...) ()
```

Comment: You might also want to check rest of the implementation of `LogError` to verify that it is async safe completely. Hint: `printf`, `fprintf`, `sprintf` or any C++ streaming API won't be async safe. The POSIX `write` function is safe.

Comment: @user2079303 `s[n]printf()` can be async-signal-safe.  It's not mandated by POSIX, but some implementations of `s[n]printf()` are async-signal-safe, such as Solaris.  So it can be possible to use `s[n]printf()` to create a string and then use `write()` to emit the string.

Comment: If you're wondering how `s[n]printf` could _not_ be async-signal-safe, any C library function that isn't _mandated_ to be async-signal-safe is allowed to use `malloc` internally for scratch space (and I can attest that GNU libc's `*printf` implementation definitely does do that).

Comment: @AndrewHenle but it's not portable to use `s[n]printf` because not all systems implement it async safely. What would be safe is to copy the source of `s[n]printf` from a system that does implement it async safely, compile it with a different name, and use that instead of the system provided one. First one must verify that copying the source is license-safe operation :)

Comment: @zwol [glibc does much worse than just merely using `malloc()`.](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/vsnprintf.c;h=39b55005280a8a8323b5747d2405c16e61a97af2;hb=HEAD).  That's the underlying implementation of glibc's `snprintf()`.  It uses a static memory buffer probably obtained with something like `fmemopen()` - with locks.  So it's not only non-async-signal-safe, it'll contend with itself if even just *used* from multiple threads.  Ooof, that's ugly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't think it's quite that bad, there's a separate `_IO_strnfile` object for every call to snprintf, allocated from snprintf's stack frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gettimeofday` is not defined as async-signal-safe, but if you pass 0 for the second (timezone) argument, it doesn't have to do anything that `time` and `clock_gettime` (both of which *are* officially async-signal-safe) don't also do, so as a matter of QoI it should be async-signal-safe in that case.

Your deadlock is inside the internal libc function `__tz_convert`.

```
#2  0x00007fc1b2d70d47 in __tz_convert () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000000004708f7 in Logger::getCurrentTimestamp(char*) ()
```

It appears to have been called directly from `Logger::getCurrentTimestamp`, but that's because it was "tail called" from a documented API function.  There are only four functions in GNU libc that call `__tz_convert` (I grepped the source code): `localtime`, `localtime_r`, `gmtime`, and `gmtime_r`.  Therefore, your problem is not that you are calling `gettimeofday`, but that you are calling one of those functions.

`localtime` and `gmtime` are obviously not async-signal-safe since they write to a global variable.  `localtime_r` and `gmtime_r` are not async-signal-safe either, because they have to look at the global database of timezone information (yes, even `gmtime_r` does this — it might be possible to change it not to need to do that, but it still wouldn't be a thing you could rely on cross-platform).

I don't think there's a good workaround.  Formatted output from an async signal handler is going to trip over all kinds of other problems; my advice is to restructure your code so that you never *need* to call logging functions from async signal handlers.

Comment: [gettimeofday](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/gettimeofday.c#L49) (in glibc at least) calls `localtime_r` which as you point out calls `__tz_convert` (which has a lock and is therefore very much async unsafe). The problem is in fact (very likely) the call to `gettimeofday`.

Comment: @user2079303 That can't be OP's immediate problem, because then `gettimeofday` would be on the stack, since that's not a tail call.  However, it's a good point anyway; I forgot about the timezone out-parameter to `gettimeofday` (because I've never seen anyone pass anything other than NULL -- you will notice that `localtime_r` is only called when tz is not NULL).  Will adjust answer.

Comment: Is the shown stack trace from the thread of execution, or from the signal handler? I think that the execution is in `__tz_convert` one way or another (not by the call to `gettimeofday` necessarily, as it is not in the call stack after all) and the lock has been acquired, and at that moment the execution is interrupted and the signal handler calls `gettimeofday` specifically, which also tries to acquire the lock, and blocks indefinitely.

Comment: @user2079303 I think you're right that the deadlock is on the lock acquired inside `__tz_convert`, but, again, `gettimeofday` doesn't call `localtime_r` unless its timezone argument is nonzero, and that call isn't a tail call,.  Therefore, if `Logger::getCurrentTimestamp` called `gettimeofday` with a nonzero timezone argument, we would see `gettimeofday` on the stack.  We don't.  Therefore I deduce that `Logger::getCurrentTimestamp` called one of localtime/localtime_r/gmtime/gmtime_r directly.

Comment: @zwol You have pointed me in the right direction. I have added definition of `Logger::getCurrentTimestamp` and stack trace of thread that received signal. It looks like call to `localtime()` might be taking lock and causing deadlock. So I have decided to remove `LogInfo()` statement from signal handler as logging is not important for me. But if I want to print logs in future within signal handler, how can I do it ?

Comment: @Durgesh I'm afraid the last paragraph of my answer is the best advice I can give you on that subject.

Answer (score 5):

`gettimeofday` itself is not signal safe, as you already found out.

However, *"POSIX.1-2008 marks gettimeofday() as obsolete, recommending the use of clock_gettime(2) instead."*([source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html#CONFORMING_TO)) and [`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) is [signal-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) (and also thread-safe), so that might be an alternative for you.

Comment: If it is not async signal safe, can it cause deadlock ?

Comment: You mean `gettimeofday`? If it not explicitly marked as such, anything can happen. It's UB (undefined behavoir).