# Synchronization issue with usage of pthread_kill() to terminate thread blocked for I/O

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, synchronization

Previously I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52391701/pthread-kill-vs-pthread-cancel-to-terminate-a-thread-blocked-for-i-o) regarding how to terminate thread blocked for I/O. I have used `pthread_kill()` instead of `pthread_cancel()` or writing to pipes, considering few advantages.

I have implementing the code to send signal (SIGUSR2) to the target thread using `pthread_kill()`. Below is the skeleton code for this. Most of the times `getTimeRemainedForNextEvent()` returns a value that blocks poll() for several hours. Because of this large timeout value, even if Thread2 sets terminateFlag (to stop Thread1), Thread2 gets blocked till poll() of Thread1 returns (which might be after several hours if there are no events on sockets). So I'm sending signal to Thread1 using `pthread_kill()` to interrupt poll() system call (if it gets blocked).

```
static void signalHandler(int signum) {
    //Does nothing
}

// Thread 1 (Does I/O operations and handles scheduler events). 

void* Thread1(void* args) {
    terminateFlag = 0;
    while(!terminateFlag) {
        int millis = getTimeRemainedForNextEvent(); //calculate maximum number of milliseconds poll() can block.

        int ret = poll(fds,numOfFDs,millis);
        if(ret > 0) {
            //handle socket events.
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                perror("Poll Error");
            break;
        }

        handleEvent();  
    }
}

// Thread 2 (Terminates Thread 1 when Thread 1 needs to be terminated)

void* Thread2(void* args) {
    while(1) {

    /* Do other stuff */

    if(terminateThread1) {
            terminateFlag = 1;
            pthread_kill(ftid,SIGUSR2); //ftid is pthread_t variable of Thread1
            pthread_join( ftid, NULL );
        }
    }

    /* Do other stuff */
}
```

Above code works fine if Thread2 sets terminateFlag and sends signal to Thread1 when it blocked in poll() system call. But, If context switch happens after `getTimeRemainedForNextEvent()` function of Thread1 and Thread2 sets terminateFlag and sends signal, poll() of Thread1 gets blocked for several hours as it lost the signal that interrupts the system call.

It seems I can not use mutex for synchronization as poll() will hold the lock till it gets unblocked. Is there any synchronization mechanism that I can apply to avoid the above mentioned issue ?

Comment: You might look into using `ppoll()` with an appropriate signal mask instead of `poll()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, access to shared variable `terminateFlag` by multiple threads [*must*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12) be protected by a mutex or similar synchronization mechanism, else your program does not conform and all bets are off.  That might, for instance, look like this:

```
void *Thread1(void *args) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    terminateFlag = 0;
    while(!terminateFlag) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);

        // ...

        pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
}

void* Thread2(void* args) {
    // ...

    if (terminateThread1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
        terminateFlag = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
        pthread_kill(ftid,SIGUSR2); //ftid is pthread_t variable of Thread1
        pthread_join( ftid, NULL );
    }

    // ...
}
```

**But that does not solve the main problem**, that a signal sent by thread 2 may be delivered to thread 1 after it tests `terminateFlag` but before it calls `poll()`, though it does narrow the window in which that could happen.

The cleanest solution is that suggested already by @PaulSanders' answer: have thread 2 wake thread 1 via a file descriptor that thread 1 is polling (i.e. by means of a pipe).  Inasmuch as you seem to have a plausible reason to seek an alternative approach, however, it should also be possible to make your signaling approach work by appropriate use of signal masking.  Expanding on @Shawn's comment, here's how it would work:

1. The parent thread blocks `SIGUSR2` before starting thread 1, so that the latter, which inherits its signal mask from its parent, starts with that signal blocked.
2. Thread 1 uses `ppoll()` instead of `poll()`, so as to be able to specify that `SIGUSR2` will be unblocked for the duration of that call.  `ppoll()` does signal mask handling atomically, so that there is no opportunity for a signal to be lost when it is blocked before the call and unblocked within.
3. Thread 2 uses `pthread_kill()` to send `SIGUSR2` to thread 1 to make it stop.  Because that signal is only unblocked for that thread when it is performing a `ppoll()` call, it will not be lost (blocked signals remain pending until unblocked).  This is precisely the kind of usage scenario for which `ppoll()` is designed.
4. You should even be able to do away with the `terminateThread` variable and associated synchronization, because you should be able to rely upon the signal being delivered during a `ppoll()` call and therefore causing the `EINTR` code path to be exercised. That path does not rely on `terminateThread` to make the thread stop.

Comment: You don't need a mutex to protect the shared variable.  `std::atomic` is sufficient.  But +1 for ppoll.

Comment: I'm implementing ppoll(). If Thread2 set terminateFlag and sent signal to Thread1 when execution is between ppoll() and end of while() loop, Thread1 exits without handling the signal (as it is blocked). In this case, Does the signal sent by Thread2 would be in pending state or discarded ?

Comment: @Durgesh, I'm having trouble finding explicit documentation to this effect, but as far as I am aware, if a thread terminates while it has a signal pending then that signal is effectively ignored.  However, I do recommend that you drop the `terminateThread` variables, as you have to do the signaling regardless, and that does not need the variable.  At most, make the variable a *local* one, and have the thread set it itself on the `EINTR` code path instead of expecting some other thread to set it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I agree with you regarding setting flag locally within the thread on `EINTR`. But is there any way to set this flag only for SIGUSR2 signal. I mean, is there any way to know which signal interrupted ppoll() system call ?

Comment: @Durgesh, in a single-threaded-scenario, you could have the signal handler record the signal number in a variable of type `volatile sigatomic_t`, but for a multithreaded scenario such as yours, I don't see how you bind that to the right thread.  Your best bet is probably to block *all* signals that can be blocked and whose disposition is something other than termination, and have `ppoll` unblock only `SIGUSR2`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider having an additional file descriptor in the set of fds passed to `poll` whose sole job is to make `poll` return when you want to terminate the thread.

Thus, in thread 2 we would have something like:

```
if (terminateThread1) {
        terminateFlag = 1;
        send (terminate_fd, " ", 1, 0);
        pthread_join (ftid, NULL);
    }
}
```

And `terminate_fd` would be in the set of fds passed to `poll` by thread 1.

-- OR --

If the overhead of having an extra fd per thread is too much (as discussed in the comments) then send something to one of the existing fds that thread 1 ignores.  This will cause poll to return and then thread 1 will terminate.  You can even have this 'special' value act as the terminate flag, which makes the logic a little tidier.

Comment: There can be more than 5000 threads which are similar to Thread1. I can't use dedicated FD for each and every thread.

Comment: Why not?  A file descriptor is not particularly heavyweight.  How many fds is each thread waiting on?  That would give a better estimate of the overhead of this approach.

Comment: Ours is a live streaming media server. For each and every connected camera, a dedicated thread will be spawned. Each thread waits on 2 sockets. So, if 20000 cameras are connected, the process needs to have 60K FDs considering dedicated FD per thread to terminate it. This limits the maximum number of cameras per sever as we have FD limit of process set to 60K

Comment: Perhaps you can send something (which thread 1 would ignore) to one of your existing fds.  Waking up the poll by sending something to it is the key to this.

Comment: Ok. I will check the possibility of implementing such logic, if I don't get resolution to the problem that I had mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

As you say yourself, you could use thread cancellation to solve this.
Outside of thread cancellation, I don't think there's a "right" way to solve this within POSIX (waking up the `poll` call with a `write` isn't exactly a generic method that would work for all situations in which a thread might get blocked), because POSIX's paradigm for making syscalls
and handling signals simply doesn't allow you to close the gap between a flag check and a potentially long blocking call.

```
void handler() { dont_enter_a_long_blocking_call_flg=1; }
int main()
{  //...
    if(dont_enter_a_long_blocking_call_flg)
        //THE GAP; what if the signal arrives here ?
        potentially_long_blocking_call();
    //....
}
```

The [musl libc library](http://www.musl-libc.org/) uses signals for thread cancellation (because signals can break long-blocking calls that are in kernel mode)
and it uses them in conjunction with global assembly labels so that from the flag setting SIGCANCEL handler, it can do
(conceptually, I'm not pasting their actual code):

```
void sigcancel_handler(int Sig, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uctx)
{
    thread_local_cancellation_flag=1;
    if_interrupted_the_gap_move_Program_Counter_to_start_cancellation(Uctx);
}
```

Now if you changed `if_interrupted_the_gap_move_Program_Counter_to_start_cancellation(Uctx);`
to `if_interrupted_the_gap_move_Program_Counter_to_make_the_syscall_fail(Uctx);` and exported the `if_interrupted_the_gap_move_Program_Counter_to_make_the_syscall_fail` function along with the `thread_local_cancellation_flag`.

then you can use it to*:

- solve your problem robustly
  implement robust signal cancelation with any signal without having to put any of that `pthread_cleanup_{push,pop}` stuff into your already working thread-safe singel threaded code
- ensure assured normal-context reaction to a signal delivery in your target thread even if the signal is handled.

Basically without a libc extension like this, if you once `kill()/pthread_kill()` a process/thread with a signal it handles or if put a function on a signal-sending timer, you cannot be sure of an assured reaction to the signal delivery, as the target may well receive the signal in a gap like above and hang indefinitely instead of responding to it.

I've implemented such a libc extension on top of musl libc and published it now https://github.com/pskocik/musl. The [SIGNAL_EXAMPLES](https://github.com/pskocik/musl/tree/master/SIGNAL_EXAMPLES) directory also shows some `kill()`, `pthread_kill`, and `setitimer()` examples that under a demonstrated race condition hang with classical libcs but don't wit my extended musl. You can use that extended musl to solve your problem cleanly and I also use it in my personal project to do robust thread cancellation without having to litter my code with `pthread_cleanup_{push,pop}`

The obvious downside of this approach is that it's unportable and I only have it implemented for x86_64 musl. I've published it today in the hope that somebody (Cygwin, MacOSX?) copies it, because I think it's the right way to do cancellation in C.

In C++ and with glibc, you could utilize the fact that glibc uses exceptions to implement thread cancellation and simply use `pthread_cancel` (which uses a signal (SIGCANCEL) underneath) but catch it instead of letting it kill the 
thread.

---

Note:

I'm really using two thread-local flags -- a breaker flag that breaks the next syscall with ECANCELED if set before the syscall is entered (an EINTR returned from a potentially long-blocking syscall gets turned into ECANCELED in the modified libc-provided syscall wrapper iff the breaking flag is set) and a saved breaking flag -- the moment a breaking flag has been used it's saved in the saved breaking flag and zeroed so that the breaking flag doesn't break futher potentially long blocking syscalls.

The idea is that cancelling signals are handled one at a time (the signal handler can be left with all/most signals blocked; the handler code (if any) can then unblock them) and that correctly checking code starts unwinding, i.e., cleaning up while returning errors, the moment it sees an ECANCELED. Then, the next potentially long blocking syscall could be in the cleanup code (e.g., code that writes `</html>` to a socket) and that syscall must be enterrable (if the breaking flag stayed on, it wouldn't be). Of course with cleanup code having e.g., `write(1,"</html>",...)` in it, it could block indefinitely too, but you could write the cleanup code so that the potentially long-blocking syscall there runs under a timer when the cleanup is due to an error (ECANCELED is an error). As I've already mentioned, robust, race-condition free, signal driven timers is one of the things this extension allows.

The EINTR => ECANCELED translation happens so that code looping on EINTR knows when to stop looping (many EINTR (=signal interrupted a syscall) cannot be prevented and the code should simply handle them by retrying the syscall. I'm using ECANCELED as an "EINTR after which you shouldn't retry."